# play only audio track in the background by AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I have a .mp4 file, with video track and audio track. I would like to play only the audio track in the background, is there any way to do that by **AVFoundation**?

or other framework?

any idea would be appreciate

Comment: I hope that my answer serves as an acceptable answer (if so please hit the checkmark to accept the answer), otherwise if more information is required please comment.

Comment: thank you for your answer. as you can see, this was post last year, I changed the app's struct that time. I still want to get the answer. But the main point of the question is, how to play only audio track by AVfoundation. I think your answer is focus on the app-level setting, which is a a different point

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've posted a revised solution that I hope will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised Solution**

I think the following link/sample will help you resolve the issue. The answer lies with the ability to disable the video track before you choose to play the asset.

[How to mute a video's audio track](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/66161-how-to-mute-video-s-audio-solved.html) is an example that one can invert and extrapolate a solution for how to disable a video track. This capability seems possible when one considers that video is just another AVPlayerItemTrack of the asset:

[image: AVFoundation AVPlayerItemTrack]

I think the key component is disabling the AVPlayerItemTrack containing the video from within the myTracks array instead of the audio track being disabled. You will need to isolate the appropriate criteria to distinguish the video track from your Audio R and Audio L tracks. I believe this framework will lead to success. Let me know how things work out.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if(context == &TracksStatusContext && [Utilities 
                   getSettings].videoMuted == YES)
    {
        NSArray * myTracks = self.myPlayerItem.tracks;
        for(int i = 0; i < [myTracks count]; i++)
        {
            if([[[myTracks objectAtIndex:i] assetTrack].mediaType 
                            isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeAudio] == YES)
            {
                ((AVPlayerItemTrack *)[myTracks 
                            objectAtIndex:i]).enabled = NO;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if (context == &ItemStatusContext) {
        [self.myPlayerView.player play];
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

[Apple AVFoundation Reference Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1)